# How to link my WebLogic users in my ADF application

Tags: java, security, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I tried to solve this problem by myself before coming here. I'll try to explain the problem clearly. I have a WebLogic server with my user list and my groups. I have also an ADF application secured with "ADF Authentication and Authorization". I try to assign rights to my WebLogic users from JDeveloper.

I have tried to create an entreprise role in my application with the same name of one of my weblogics groups. And I gave the good rights to this group, but i still cannot access to the page.

I think that users or groups i manage in my application are not linked with the weblogic users. The Realm used in my application is "jazn.com", I think that I must change that, but how ?

thanks

Comment: Can you post what sort of access errors you see in the Weblogic logs? It's hard to tell from your post what could be happening without any errors. Does this help? http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/02/01/weblogic-web-application-container-security-part-2-adf-security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can link your users in this way:

a) You have this tag in your web.xml file:

<"security-role>
    <"description>Role Description <"/description>
    <"role-name>my_role<"/role-name>
<"/security-role>

b) You need to create a weblogic.xml file inside WEB-INF folder, with the following content:

<"?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<"weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <"security-role-assignment>
        <"role-name>my_role<"/role-name>
        <"principal-name>group_name<"/principal-name>
    <"/security-role-assignment>
<"/weblogic-web-app>

Here is where you specify that the role that you set in your jazn-data.xml file will be assigned to the users in the group that you specify in the principal-name tag. This is linked with your default realm, I think you can add other tag specifying the realm if you need a different realm.

Note: I added a lot of quotes after "<" because I don't know how to show xml code. Erase those quotes after copying it

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know the steps you took, and as asked, the error messages you see and the version of JDeveloper.
In the meantime, these video tutorials may help.
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/AdfSecurity/AdfSecurity.html
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adf_security1/adf_security1.html
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adf_security2/adf_security2.html
http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adf_oam_integration/adf_oam_integration.html